# How to connect to ArcGIS Server on the other machine?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, c#

There is the ArcGis Server on the machine 192.168.**.22

Machine name is MAPSERVER.

User name and password for ArcgIS Server are "test" and "testtest" (for example)

ArcGis Server options are: clusters - name "default", computer "MAPSEVER", protocol "TCP port 4004".

I want to connect to this ArcGis Server. I used code

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Identity identity = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Identity("test", "testtest", "default");
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.AGS.AGSServerConnection agsconnection;
agsconnection = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.AGS.AGSServerConnection("MAPSERVER", identity);
agsconnection.Connect();
IServerObjectManager SOM = agsconnection.ServerObjectManager;
```

I get error `

> "Identity error"

Comment: Few questions to you 1.Which version you are using (I think you are using 10.0)2.Are you want to make connection using ADF ?3.Is there same license level for both machines? (like Advance-Advance) 4.Both machines have same versions for AGS? 5.Is there any firewall enabled between two machine?

Comment: 1) ArcGis Desktop 10.1, license: ArcInfo - floating license (on my machine); ArcGis Server 10.1, ArcGis Desktop 10.1, license: ArcInfo - floating license (on server).

2) No. It is not principle.

3) Yes

4) Yes

5) No

Comment: Could you please explain your question in detail? Because I was wondering that how you are connecting the ArcGIS Server (Through code/some application/desktop,Arc Catalog etc) & I guess that your machine have only the code and through that code you are connecting the AGS server is that correct?

Comment: I use this code: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/adf/dotnet/developer/ADF/connection_manager.htm


http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=1702&t=245475

Comment: I do not know what kind of information do I need to substitute at domain, host, password, user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web ADF was discontinued in 10.0 and above.  The help you cited was from the 9.3 help.  Now ESRI wants you to use either [Geoprocessing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Alternatives_to_server_object_extensions/015400000528000000/) models or [Server Object Extensions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004s5000000).